# Magento SOAP v2 attributes parameter for product

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2

According to the [API Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html), one can specify an array of attributes as a parameter when retrieving a product. What is the purpose in that?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `attributes` (it's a Array of `catalogProductRequestAttributes`) It is used to define which attributes about a product to retrieve in request response.

Note that the additional attributes will be returned in through the associative array named `additional_attributes` in `catalogProductReturnEntity`.

Example to retrive just product title, description, short description and price attributes.

```
// connect to soap server
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentoinstall.local/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

// log in
$session = $client->login('user', 'pass');

// product info
$attributes = new stdclass();
$attributes->attributes = array('product_title', 'description', 'short_description', 'price');
$productInfo = $client->catalogProductInfo($session, 'sku', NULL, $attributes);
```

Doing an analogy with Magento Collections, this has an effect similar to `addAttributeToSelect()` method.

Comment: when you create products, you can add attribute sets to them. How do I access the attributes and attribute values for a product?

Comment: You can retrieve this via `catalogProductAttributeList` method: https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.list.html

Comment: yes, but that does not give me the attributes for one product. It gives me all attributes in the store.

Comment: Could you tell me how to retrieve the label from an attribute that is populated from a dropdown? I can get the ID of the dropdown option from the method you mentioned, but not the descriptive label. (i.e - product_type is returning '5' and not 'Magazine')

Comment: @DenisSpalenza can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/263298/57334

Comment: @zus I checked your question. I'll anwser it tomorrow.

Comment: May I know any points? @Denis